# How to get 2d representation for a 3d object

Tags: solidworks

I've created a 3d object and I want to cut the exact shape on a fabric to cover it

Is there a way to "flatten" it?
Lets say its a cube, so this is the 2d result i'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Sheetmetal mode?

Comment: As joojaa already mentioned solidwoks has a sheet metal mode, and you can create objects with sheets of metal, which then you can easily flatter. Probably J.R.Swift can tell you if there is another way with generic 3d shapes (extrusion etc).

Comment: I would use sheet metal too, but it gets complicated if there is complex curvature rather than simple folds or bends and requires a premium license for that

Comment: What if the shape has curves and such?
I have premium

Comment: my mom knew sewing, couture, in french. she could fashion anything out of fabric. I am sure you know most of the general 3d shapes can not be modeled by generated surfaces. That is how an ant can verify it lives on a sphere.

Comment: There's no unique "unfolding" solution, even for simple shapes like this.  What's your ultimate goal here?

Comment: To cut Carbon fiber to the exact size of the mould

Answer (score 1):

First thing that popped in my mind was [Pepakura](https://tamasoft.co.jp/pepakura-en/productinfo/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think the words you're looking for are unfolding/unwrapping.
There are a lot of software that can do this, which is more suitable depends on your application.

Here is a good starting point :-)

https://www.instructables.com/Design-Papercrafts-with-CAD-software/